# Looping through a collection of data - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash, html-table

I have a Ruby / Rails view where-in the employee names will be displayed on the Y-axis (Left side) and Week Dates on top starting from Sunday and ending on Saturday of the week.

```
            '2017-02-05'    '2017-02-06'    '2017-02-07'    '2017-02-08'    '2017-02-09'   '2017-02-10'   '2017-02-11'

Employee_1       7                                                3             4.5

Employee_2                      4               6.2              0.5                          10.5
```

When I pull the details from database, the data will be in the below form. The Date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
@data = 
    {"Employee_1"=>
      [{"week_date"=>"2017-02-05",
        "log_time"=>"7"},
       {"week_date"=>"2017-02-08",
        "log_time"=>"3"},
       {"week_date"=>"2017-02-09",
        "log_time"=>"4.5"}],
     "Employee_2"=>
      [{"week_date"=>"2017-02-06",
        "log_time"=>"4"},
       {"week_date"=>"2017-02-07",
        "log_time"=>"6.2"},
       {"week_date"=>"2017-02-08",
        "log_time"=>"0.5"},
       {"week_date"=>"2017-02-10",
        "log_time"=>"10.5"}]
    }
```

Also, we have an array that contains the week days:

```
@week_days = ["2017-02-05", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-07", "2017-02-08",  "2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", "2017-02-11"]
```

How can I just loop this structure and display data for the dates for which the data is available and skip rest of the dates in the HTML table structure in the view?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: There isn't much that I can show. I could only print the Employee name which we can show on the first <td></td> of each <tr></tr>. But displaying data in the rest of the TD's in a row seems to be little tricky..We have to match up with the week date and if data is available show it in the corresponding TD and if not leave as blank.

Comment: You can loop over the data in your view usong ERB. You can loop twice if it makes writing the table easoer (once for th and again for td)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s start with a preparation step. We’ll need a `stub` week days, we’ll later use as a scaffold for the original data:

```
stub = @week_days.map { |wd| {wd => ""} }.reduce(&:merge)
```

and a reducer for the original data:

```
reducer = ->(v) {
  v.map { |h| {h["week_date"] => h["log_time"]} }.reduce(&:merge)
}
```

OK, we are all set.

```
@data.map { |k, v| [k, stub.merge(reducer.(v))] }.to_h
#⇒ {
#  "Employee_1" => {
#    "2017-02-05" => "7",
#    "2017-02-06" => "",
#    "2017-02-07" => "",
#    "2017-02-08" => "3",
#    "2017-02-09" => "4.5",
#    "2017-02-10" => "",
#    "2017-02-11" => ""
#  },
#  "Employee_2" => {
#    "2017-02-05" => "",
#    "2017-02-06" => "4",
#    "2017-02-07" => "6.2",
#    "2017-02-08" => "0.5",
#    "2017-02-09" => "",
#    "2017-02-10" => "10.5",
#    "2017-02-11" => ""
#  }
# }
```

Now just iterate the above and print values.